# How to horizontally align list item child elements with dynamic data with CSS

Tags: css

I'm wondering if its possible using CSS to horizontally align each child-element within a collection of items (`<section>`in code snippet) when the title (`<h1>` in code snippet) and description (`<p>` in code snippet) can have dynamic lengths.

For this to work, each parent elements height would have to adjust to be the same height as the largest parent element on the same line.

I don't want to explicitly set the height of each item (`<section>`), to keep items dynamically as small as possible.

The end result should have the first line of all item child-elements aligned horizontally to all its neighbouring item child-elements.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

section {
  width: 272px;
  height: 321px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 50px;
}

.img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 64px;
}

div, h1, p {
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;  
}

h1 {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

p {
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <h1>This is a short title</h1>
    
      <p>This is a short description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="download">Download</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <h1>This is a much longer title that will push the description element down too far, so that it is no longer aligned with the first section desc</h1>
    
      <p>This is a short description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="download">Download</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <h1>This is a short title </h1>
    
      <p>This is an extra long description that will push upwards so that the text can fit, but again is no longer aligned horizontally to first</p>
  </div>

  <div class="download">Download</div>
</section>
```

Comment: with pure css, you can't :/ You need some js.

Comment: you would need a grid & asubgrid. display:contents could help you here with grid : https://jsfiddle.net/2h9L6o8s/